# How are weather-related limits on arrival capacity determined?

Tags: airport-capacity

Most airports in Europe have the following traffic controls imposed during adverse weather conditions. I wonder whether these capacity limits are determined by airport operator's experience, or if there are any special algorithms?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ATC has to keep planes a minimum distance apart, and that distance increases as weather gets worse. You could fairly easily calculate from the required spacing in each case to get an expected arrival rate, but the real world never works exactly as planned. The numbers in that table have almost certainly been "adjusted" to make them agree with experience.